# Find the most frequent occurring character in a string

Tags: algorithm, swift, swift2

I'm trying to find the most **succinct**, **short**, **concise** way to express the algorithm to find the **most frequent occurring character in a string**.

My algorithm is as follows:

1. Go through each `character` of the string
2. For each `character`, use the `hashValue` to construct a hash table with a property indicating the # of occurrences of the particular hash key
3. Go through the hash table and find the greatest value and un hash the key back to the a `character`

Here's my solution. I've hit a roadblock near the end; I have correctly located the greatest occurring `hashValue` via that algorithm, but I do not know how to map the hash key back to a character.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as screen captures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the character itself as key to the dictionary.

```
let string = "abbcde"
var counters = [Character: Int]()

for c in string {
    if let count = counters[c] {
        counters[c] = count + 1
    } else {
        counters[c] = 1
    }
}
    
let maxElement = counters.reduce(counters.first!) { $1.1 > $0.1 ? $1 : $0 }
print(maxElement.0) // prints "b"
```

Updated to swift 4 syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @hennes solution there is even a shorter one:

```
let string = "abbcde"
var counters = [Character: Int]()

for c in string {
    counters[c] = (counters[c] ?? 0) + 1
}

let maxElement = counters.reduce(counters.first!) { $1.1 > $0.1 ? $1 : $0 }
print(maxElement.0) // prints "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only iterate the sequence once:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
  func mostFrequent() -> Generator.Element? {
    var freqs: [Generator.Element:Int] = [:]
    return maxElement { (bc, ec) in
      let en = freqs[ec]?.successor() ?? 1
      freqs[ec] = en
      return en > freqs[bc]
    }
  }
}

"aabcccdee" // "c"
  .characters
  .mostFrequent()
```

Or, if you wanted to be really golfy:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
  func mostFrequent() -> Generator.Element? {
    var fs: [Generator.Element:Int] = [:]
    return maxElement { (bc, ec) in fs[ec]?++ ?? fs.updateValue(1, forKey: ec) >= fs[bc] }
  }
}

"aaaabcccdee"
  .characters
  .mostFrequent()
```

Outside of a method:

```
var fs: [Character:Int] = [:]
let mostFrequent = "aaaeabcceced".characters
  .maxElement { (bc, ec) in fs[ec]?++ ?? fs.updateValue(1, forKey: ec) >= fs[bc] }
```